# Onclick effect. text (+1) pop up from cursor (like on cookie clicker)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, fade

I've recently made a webpage quite similar to the famous 'Cookie Clicker' game (Google Cookie Clicker if you don't know what it is), and I was wondering how the 'onclick' effect for the cookie (from cookie clicker) is done.

When you click the cookie on Cookie Clicker, a text box saying +1 pops up from your cursor, and then proceeds to fade away. Feel free to check out the effect yourselves on the original Cookie Clicker page (I REALLY prefer the effect on the classic cookie clicker, which you can find on a href link in the top right corner on the current version of cookie clicker).

My onclick image (which, by the way, isn't a cookie) already has onclick/mouseover effects (clickcounter/audio effects), so I would need something that cooperates with what I've already got. In addition, the cookie clicker also provides a small cookie to pop up and fade away in the same manner as the +1 text, which would also be really amazing on my site.

You can also check out my page by clicking the link on my StackExchange profile.

I've been sitting here, all day, trying to script this, but my only results are my script crashing or my buttons disappearing from my webpage. Could someone please help me with this? Additional information about my script will be provided if necessary (in comments).

Thanks to all in advance!

-Daniel

(these are my current scripts for my onclick effects/button. All the sources are local files.)

**Javascript**

```
function clickCounter(){
     var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
     audio.play();
     if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
         if (localStorage.clickcount)
         {
             localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
         }
         else
         {
             localStorage.clickcount=1;
         }
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<center><b>You have clicked the poop
         </b>"+ localStorage.clickcount + "<b> times!</b></center>";
     }
     else{
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="I'm sorry to inform you that your browser
         does not support this web storage... I guess you could say that your browser is...
         shit! awwww yeaahh!";
     }
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<center>
     <font face="chiller" color="#603913" "font size="300" <align="center"><b>Click the
     poop!</b>
</center>
<center>
    <p><picture onclick="clickCounter()"><picture
     onmouseover="document.getElementById('touch').play()"><img src="poop.png"></button></p>
</center>
<audio id="audio" src="fart-01.wav"></audio>
<audio id="touch" src="sticky goo.wav"></audio>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your actual question. Just som feedback on your HTML. Both `center` and `font` are deprecated tags. Your HTML element should purely be structural, try styling your HTML by using CSS instead. If you want to read up on which tags are deprecated you can do so here: [HTML Deprecated Tags](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_deprecated_tags.htm)

Comment: I posted this question earlier (without the scripts) and people wanted me to post the scripts in the question, so I did. It's there for people who might need to see my scripts in order to add the desired effect, or for people who might need the effects that I already have

Comment: Ohh, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you meant that the script didn't have anything to do with my question, my apologies :) Thanks for your feedback. I'm new to scripting, so I know it's messy, but i do some changes every now and then. I will look into what you told me. Thanks for your interest! :)

Comment: NP :) If you're new to HTML and Javascript I could really suggest [Codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/). They have some great tutorials to help you understand the basics of coding a website.